# ZPL Barcode Labels setting width of label/barcode

Tags: zpl

I'm printing to a zebra thermal printer from 2 different systems, a windows environment using BarTender to print labels with a text file as the data source, and an older system (green screen) which prints using command files like below.

My problem is when I print from the windows printer, the printers settings change, so when I then print from the other system, it loses the width and runs off the edge.

I tried to add a print width setting to the code below which didn't work ,^PW700 and could do with some advice! this isn't a language I know much about. I don't know if I used the code in the right way/place or if im using the right code at all? could it be that I need to use BYw?

```
^XA^LL456,^PW700^LH0,0^FS
^FO21,196^B3N,N,66,N^FDWU000208375^FS
^FO18,18^A0N,24,24^FDPrd Code : 84100705            ^FS
^FO18,48^A0N,24,24^FDDANDY GREY                              ^FS
^FO18,78^A0N,24,24^FDQuantity Remaining :       4.00^FS
^FO18,108^A0N,24,24^FDAmended : 01/07/15   Received : 01/07/15^FS
^FO18,138^A0N,24,24^FDBATCH : 241071   ^FS
^FO18,168^A0N,24,24^FD^FS
^FO129,276^A0N,24,24^FDW U 2 0 8 3 7 5
^XZ
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

It might be too late to answer this question, but it might help others.

The reason your code doesn't work might cause by comma before ^PW

> ^LL456,^PW700

So removing it should work on any system:

> ^LL456^PW700

The usual command code for zpl is

> ^(command)(parameter),(parameter)...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update. the code works fine except straight after a windows print. its a strange one but i'll test that what you mentioned and reply again.

Comment: @JustAnAverageSQLuser These settings persist to the next label, it might be that the label you are printing from Windows is changing these settings.